# Create floating TToolbar at run-time without flicker

Tags: delphi

I'm attempting to create a custom TToolbar at run-time that floats over the form (below the control it is associated with).

My issue is that the process of floating and positioning the toolbar at creation creates a hideous flicker where it is initially drawn at the top-left of the monitor before being moved to my desired position on the form.

I cannot find a way to avoid this. Is there a way?

```
procedure TMainForm.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  newToolbar : TToolbar;
  newButton : TToolButton;
begin
  newToolbar := TToolbar.Create(Self);

  newToolbar.Visible := False;

  newToolbar.ManualFloat( Rect( 0, 0, newToolbar.Width, newToolbar.Height ));

  newToolbar.Parent := Self;

  newToolbar.left := 100;
  newToolbar.Top  := 100;

  newToolbar.ShowCaptions := True;

  newButton := TToolButton.Create(Self);
  newButton.Parent := newToolbar;
  newButton.Caption := 'Test';

  newToolbar.Visible := True;
end;
```

References:
 - [Create TToolbutton runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093595/create-ttoolbutton-runtime)
 - [toolbutton with action created at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254457/toolbutton-with-action-created-at-runtime)
 - [Delphi - Create a custom TToolBar component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221057/delphi-create-a-custom-ttoolbar-component)

Comment: Why are you assigning ParentWindow?

Comment: I'd also like to see a [mcve]. That way we can easily get started debugging this. Otherwise there's every chance that we try to recreate it and fail, wasting time. For instance, perhaps the issue appears only because of other choices made in your program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That code should reproduce the issue in any application

Comment: "Should" doesn't persuade me to spend my time making an app. Never mind. Perhaps somebody else will give you their time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I tested it in three applications including a completely blank one. So it *should* work in any application (99% certainty), but I cannot *guarantee* that it will, Perhaps there is some screwy in my Delphi setup...

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Thank you for being helpful. Your suggestion led me to the solution, which I will post below...

Comment: Just move ManualFloat to after you've created and inserted the buttons, as the last line in the snippet - you don't need visible := true.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: That still gives a flash in my testing

Comment: No repro here then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little puzzled with your solution, so I provide my two takes on the subject. Specifically I don't understand why you are using `ManualFloat()` and few lines later set the parent of the toolbar, which makes it non-floating.

Here is a solution for a floating toolbar, using `ManualFloat()`. 
The toolbar is floating above the form in its own temporary `TCustomDockForm`,
at the given location.

The record needed by `ManualFloat()` is setup for the final location, thus no flicker in the wrong place, and the control
is immediately correctly positioned.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  newToolbar : TToolbar;
  newButton : TToolButton;
  p: TPoint;
begin
  newToolbar := TToolbar.Create(Self);

  // calculate position in screen coordinates for the floating toolbar
  p := ClientOrigin;
  p.Offset(100, 100);
  // and make it floating in final position
  newToolbar.ManualFloat( Rect(p.X, p.Y, p.X+NewToolbar.Width, p.Y+newToolbar.Height) );

  newToolbar.Visible := False; // really needed ?

  // Then create the toolbar buttons
  newToolbar.ShowCaptions := True;

  newButton := TToolButton.Create(self);
  newButton.Parent := newToolbar;
  newButton.Caption := 'Test';

  newToolbar.Visible := True;
end;
```

However, since you actually seem to want a non-floating toolbar, that is just
located anywhere you like on the form (and not in the default top of the form),
a better solution is to skip the `ManualFloat()` altogether and just set the
`Align` property of the toolbar to `alNone`. This enables it to be moved anywhere
on the parent form.

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  newToolbar : TToolbar;
  newButton : TToolButton;
begin
  newToolbar := TToolbar.Create(Self);
  newToolbar.Align := alNone; // constructor sets it to alTop

  newToolbar.Visible := False; // really needed ?

  newToolbar.Parent := Self;
  newToolbar.Left := 100;
  newToolbar.Top := 200;

  newToolbar.ShowCaptions := True;

  newButton := TToolButton.Create(self);
  newButton.Parent := newToolbar;
  newButton.Caption := 'Test';

  newToolbar.Visible := True; //
end;
```

This gives you the same appearance as your own code, but omits the `ManualFloat()`.

Finally, an image to show the appearances:

[image]

The bottom toolbar is created with `Button4Click()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TomBrunberg for your suggestion.

What was needed to make it position over the form without any pre-drawing:

1. Position it off-screen when ManualFloat is called
2. Set Visible to false after call to ManualFloat (because ManualFloat sets it true)

Revised code:

```
procedure TMainForm.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  newToolbar : TToolbar;
  newButton : TToolButton;
begin
  newToolbar := TToolbar.Create(Self);

  // Float with off-screen position
  newToolbar.ManualFloat( Rect( 0, -200, newToolbar.Width, newToolbar.Height - 200 ));

  // Must hide after ManualFloat call, as it resets Visible to true
  newToolbar.Visible := False;

  // Set parent so we can add buttons, sets props, etc.
  newToolbar.Parent := Self;

  // Move to desired position over form
  newToolbar.left := 100;
  newToolbar.Top  := 100;

  // Add our button content...
  newToolbar.ShowCaptions := True;

  newButton := TToolButton.Create(Self);
  newButton.Parent := newToolbar;
  newButton.Caption := 'Test';

  // Now we can show it
  newToolbar.Visible := True;
end;
```